# Reformat JSON file?

Tags: python, json, reformatting

I have two JSON files.

File A:

```
  "features": [
  {
   "attributes": {
    "NAME": "R T CO",
    "LTYPE": 64,
    "QUAD15M": "279933",
    "OBJECTID": 225,
    "SHAPE.LEN": 828.21510830520401
   },
   "geometry": {
    "paths": [
     [
      [
       -99.818614674337155,
       27.782542677671653
      ],
      [
       -99.816056346719051,
       27.782590806976135
      ]
     ]
    ]
   }
  }
```

File B:

```
  "features": [
{
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiLineString",  
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -99.773315512624,
          27.808875128096
        ],
        [
          -99.771397939251,
          27.809512259374
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "LTYPE": 64,
    "SHAPE.LEN": 662.3800009247,
    "NAME": "1586",
    "OBJECTID": 204,
    "QUAD15M": "279933"
  }
},
```

I would like File B to be reformatted to look like File A.
Change "properties" to "attributes", "coordinates" to "paths", and remove both "type": "MultiLineString" and "type": "Feature". What is the best way to do this via python?

Is there a way to also reorder the "attributes" key value pairs to look like File A?

It's a rather large dataset and I would like to iterate through the entire file.

Comment: What have you tried? There's plenty of JSON + Python answers on SO, did they get you anywhere?

Comment: The `json` module lets you load json files into python data structures and then save them back to json later. So its a question of looping through the python `dict` and `list` items you get. This is mostly a tedious book keeping operation and you get to do that part yourself!

Comment: In Python JSON objects are just dictionaries — so just read in one file, change to contents of the dictionary, and write it out and the other file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manipulating JSON in Python is a good candidate for the [input-process-output model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model) of programming.

For input, you convert the external JSON file into a Python data structure, using [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load).

For output, you convert the Python data structure into an external JSON file using [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump).

For the processing or conversion step, do whatever it is that you need to do, using ordinary Python `dict` and `list` methods.

This program might do what you want:

```
import json

with open("b.json") as b:
    b = json.load(b)

for feature in b["features"]:

    feature["attributes"] = feature["properties"]
    del feature["properties"]

    feature["geometry"]["paths"] = feature["geometry"]["coordinates"]
    del feature["geometry"]["coordinates"]

    del feature["geometry"]["type"]

    del feature["type"]

with open("new-b.json", "w") as new_b:
    json.dump(b, new_b, indent=1, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am needing. I have not used JSON library before.

Answer (score -2):

What about:

```
cat <file> | python -m json.tool
```

This will reformat the contents of the file into a uniform human readable format. If you really need to change the names of the fields you could use sed.

```
cat <file> | sed -e 's/"properties"/"attributes"/'
```

This may be sufficient for your use case. If you have something that requires more nuanced parsing, you'll have to read up on how to manage the JSON through an ORM library.

Comment: I'm not bad at handling JSON within Python but this answer makes no sense to me. What is this doing and how?

Comment: And how is this considering two json objects?

Comment: json.tool actually exists ... wow im suprised...but all it does is pretty print the json... I think

Comment: @JoranBeasley so its a pretty solution but not a pretty good solution?

Comment: @tdelaney I'm thinking "solution" needs removing there

Comment: Did you read the question? The JSON was already human-readable.

Comment: meh the sed sorta makes it a kinda solution i think ... (I almost posted a sed solution...)